# Is there an AWS security group rule specifically allowing access to AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, amazon-kms

I have a node.js server running in EC2 that uses AWS KMS to encrypt/decrypt data.
I can successfully use the aws-sdk to carry out my tasks using

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const kms = new AWS.KMS();
kms.decrypt( ... )
```

I now want to lock down my infrastructure using security groups.
I cannot work out what rule to use to allow this server to access the AWS KMS resources without having an outgoing rule allowing all traffic, anywhere:

```
Outbound rules:
Type        | Protocol | Port range | Destination
All traffic | All      | All        | 0.0.0.0/0 
All traffic | All      | All        | ::/0
```

This may be excessive, but **is there a rule I can use that specifically allows outbound access to the AWS KMS service**?

A `CIDR block, a security group ID or a prefix list has to be specified`, so I cannot use the endpoint hostname or href from the KMS service object:

```js
kms Service {
  ...
  isGlobalEndpoint: false,
  endpoint: Endpoint {
    protocol: 'https:',
    host: 'kms.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'kms.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: 'https://kms.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
  },
  ...
}
```

Inspecting the Remote Address of `https://kms.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/` provides an IP address of `52.94.48.24:443`. Using this in a specific rule works intermitently, but I can find no AWS documentation suggesting that this IP address is fixed. I would imagine it is not.

```
Type        | Protocol | Port range | Destination
HTTPS       | TCP      | 443        | 52.94.48.24/32
```

Any guidance is most appreciated!

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by locking your infrastructure we understand that you put your EC2 instances is a [private subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html). In this case you should create a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-vpc-endpoint.html) for the KMS service.

A VPC endpoint will have a network interface in your subnets, which will provide a  private IP address for every subnet and also potential private DNS hostname (if the VPC has this property enabled).

Moreover you can allow traffic between EC2 instances and VPC endpoint based on security group (no need to specify IPs).

Comment: It took me a while to really understand the set up to get this to work. I could do all the individual tasks but not quite get it to hang together, but I have it now. In the end ... [1] update the default security group to only (a) Inbound, all traffic, sg-{default} (b) Outbound, all traffic, sg-{default}  [2] assign this security group to all EC2, & RDS instances  [3]  create the VPC endpoint, assigning to the default security group. Now my system can talk amongst itself with just the one (simple) security group.

Comment: Things to note: [1] You need an outbound and inbound rule [2] I could not make this work with a security group I had made, I needed to use and update the original default security group, obviously removing 0.0.0.0/0 [3] Make sure you have applied the security group to all the assets! (EC2, RDS & Endpoints, in my case). Probably obvioous to most, but hopefully useful to someone!